# Google AppEngine deployment failure ERROR appcfg.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cloud

I'm new at Google Cloud services. I'm trying AppEngine. I'm just following the python tutorial here : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/uploading

I'm trying to deploy my file in Google but it doesn't work and I don't know why ! First I've forgotten to modify the app.yaml file but now I have filled the "application" with "direct-way-658" which is the name of my application!

Here the log information:

```
2014-07-29 14:28:47 Running command: "['C:\\python27_x64\\python.exe', '-u', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--no_cookies', u'--email=akash.myeamail@gmail.com', '--passin', 'update', 'D:\\POCGOOGLE\\guestbook']"
02:28 PM Application: direct-way-658; version: 1
02:28 PM Host: appengine.google.com
02:28 PM Starting update of app: direct-way-658, version: 1
02:28 PM Getting current resource limits.
2014-07-29 14:28:48,681 ERROR appcfg.py:2395 An error occurred processing file '': <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>. Aborting. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 126, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 122, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5334, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5325, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2963, in Run
    self.action(self)
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4991, in __call__
    return method()
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3762, in Update
    self._UpdateWithParsedAppYaml(appyaml, self.basepath)
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3815, in _UpdateWithParsedAppYaml
    self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, basepath, appyaml, APP_YAML_FILENAME)
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3698, in UpdateVersion
    return appversion.DoUpload(paths, openfunc)
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2385, in DoUpload
    self.error_fh)
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 468, in GetResourceLimits
    resource_limits.update(_GetRemoteResourceLimits(logging_context))
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 438, in _GetRemoteResourceLimits
    yaml_data = logging_context.Send('/api/appversion/getresourcelimits')
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1724, in Send
    result = self.rpcserver.Send(url, payload=payload, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 409, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
    File "C:\python27_x64\lib\urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
    File "C:\python27_x64\lib\urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
    File "C:\python27_x64\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
    File "C:\python27_x64\lib\urllib2.py", line 1222, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\fancy_urllib\fancy_urllib\__init__.py", line 387, in do_open
    raise url_error
    urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
2014-07-29 14:28:48 (Process exited with code 1)

You can close this window now.
```

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your app.yaml? Looks like its trying to upload a file with no name "An error occurred processing file '': . Aborting."

Comment: This kind of "answers" are better posted as a comment to the original question.

Comment: I can't add comments to his post till I get higher rep unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I faced something similar while trying to upload a .json file, by following the suggestion here https://gist.github.com/darktable/873098 I edited my App.yaml and added a mime type and it worked.

```
application: your_app
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /static
 static_dir: static

- url: /.*
 script: index.php

- url: /(.*\.json)
 mime_type: application/json
 static_files: static/\1
 upload: static/(.*\.json)
 expiration: "1h"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your anwsers ! But it was a proxy problem. The compagny I work for use a proxy for all it connection with internet do I had to set my enrironment variables so that Google app engine go through this proxy.

In the Google SDK shell :

set HTTP_PROXY=http:// name:pass@proxy:port
set HTTPS_PROXY=http:// name:pass@proxy:port

then lanch the app :

appcfg.py update name_of_the_app/